# ggplot labels overlapped by abline

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am using the `geom_label_repel` function to arrange labels in a way that avoids overlapping but when I add an regression line to my plot, then it itself overlaps the labels.

```
ggplot(globalMetrics, aes(x=globalMetrics$popDensity, y=globalMetrics$turnover)) + geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +  geom_label_repel(aes(label= rownames(globalMetrics)), size=3) + stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

Is there a way to avoid this in `ggplot`?

[image]

Here is a sample of the data:

```
 dput(globalMetrics)
structure(list(popDensity = c(4308, 27812, 4447, 5334, 4662, 
2890), turnover = c(2.65, 4.49, 2.37, 2.87, 3.87, 2.95)), .Names = c("popDensity", 
"turnover"), row.names = c("label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", 
"label5", "label6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you put the `stat_smooth` before the `geom_label_repel` then the labels appear on top of the line with a white background, which is an improvement

Comment: I believe there is not a good way to dodge across `ggplot` layers. Thus, I don't know if its possible to get what you want without some manual changes.